# Delete nested property of cloned object with Object.assign() affect original object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is someone can explain me this behavior ?

```
const object1 = {
  a: {
    d : 1,
    e : 4
  },
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

const object2 = Object.assign({}, object1);
console.log('object1 :', object1);
console.log('object2 :', object2);
delete object2.a;
console.log('object1 :', object1);
console.log('object2 :', object2);
```

If I delete `a`, only `object2` is affected.

```
> "object1 :" Object { a: Object { d: 1, e: 4 }, b: 2, c: 3 }
> "object2 :" Object { a: Object { d: 1, e: 4 }, b: 2, c: 3 }
> "object1 :" Object { a: Object { d: 1, e: 4 }, b: 2, c: 3 }
> "object2 :" Object { b: 2, c: 3 }
```

And if I delete a nested property...

```
const object2 = Object.assign({}, object1);
console.log('object1 :', object1);
console.log('object2 :', object2);
delete object2.a.d;
console.log('object1 :', object1);
console.log('object2 :', object2);
```

Both `object1` and `object2` lose the property `d`.

```
> "object1 :" Object { a: Object { d: 1, e: 4 }, b: 2, c: 3 }
> "object2 :" Object { a: Object { d: 1, e: 4 }, b: 2, c: 3 }
> "object1 :" Object { a: Object { e: 4 }, b: 2, c: 3 }
> "object2 :" Object { a: Object { e: 4 }, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

Why ?

Comment: `Object.assign` creates only a same level copy, not the nested ones.

Comment: @NinaScholz So the nested ones are juste references ?

Comment: right, nested objects are taken as reference.

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted ? I find it useful to understand Object.assign and delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing :

```
const object2 = Object.assign({}, object1);
```

You are assigning the properties of `object1` to a new object, that will be stored in `object2`. In your case there is only one property of `object1`, that is `a`. **But this is the same `a` that you put in object2 and that is in object1**

Then, this line :

```
delete object2.a;
```

Just deletes the reference of the property `a` from `object2`. The property itself is not changed and will still exist if there are some other attached references to it.

In your second case, when you do :

```
delete object2.a.d;
```

you actually delete the reference of the property `d` from the object referenced by `object2.a`, which, remember, is the same as the object referenced by `object1.a`, so it indeed appears changed in both `object1` and `object2`

Comment: can u elobrate ?

Comment: In your second case you mutate the object a ? it means?

Answer (score 3):

On examples section in the documentation of assign (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> Warning for Deep Clone
>
> For deep cloning, we need to use other alternatives because
>   Object.assign() copies property values. If the source value is a
>   reference to an object, it only copies that reference value.

There are a specific example on how to deep clone an object:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1))
```

And if you want more info about, there's an old thread on SO over this issue:

[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/5344074#5344074)

Answer (score 0):

Hi [reffered from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

You can use OBJECT COPY AS following

```
const object1 = {
  a: {
    d : 1,
    e : 4
  },
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

const objecct2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object1));
```

Comment: How is this different from @Marc answer ?

Comment: after I posted only I got page refreshed, So I have spend some time, So I do not want to delete.